# How make the canvas same as the screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I am making a mobile game. My problem is that on different mobiles the canvas and the camera size changes. So some things some things is cut out of the screen while in others it a little short and empty blue space is visible.

Comment: That's a quite normal issue. I would recommend to search for unity + resolutions.
There is a [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1731052/mobile-game-different-screen-size-issue.html) of an useful post in unity forums.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with the different UI Scale Modes, under "Canvas Scaler"?

Comment: Is this asking OP for more info or is this an answer?